# Pulling stats out of a text

Tags: ruby, nlp

I'd like to know what are the most recurrent in a given text or group of text (pulled from a database) in ruby.

Does anyone know what are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start with [statistical natural language processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_grammar). Also, you may be able to leverage one or more of the libraries mentioned on the [AI Ruby Plugins](http://web.media.mit.edu/~dustin/rubyai.html) page.